# Firefox for Android - address bar overlaps content. Is there a solution?

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I am working on a web page, that has to be 100% high. I did it so, it works fine everywhere, except on Android Firefox.
The problem is:

When I open the page for first time, in landscape mode - the address bar overlaps the content.

If I do orientation change - it gets OK in portrait mode, and when I go back to landscape mode - it's OK there too. The problem appears only in landscape mode, before any (eventual) orientation change.

Tried many things, mostly some scrollTo() solutions, but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just how the Firefox app works. You could state in your (CSS) style sheet a 10 to 15 pixel "margin-top" for the body. This would create a black space at the top of the page. You could just adjust that height accordingly.

You could also try to check for that browser with a javascript and specify a new CSS with the "margin-top" adjustment if you didn't want it to adjust except on the Firefox app.